# Is SharedPreferences not accessible to other applications?

Tags: android

I have an app which has a user login to a webservice (username + password). I need to store the user's username and password somewhere to auto-log them in (otherwise they have to enter username + password every time).

I have stored the username + password in SharedPreferences like so:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.put("username", "the username");
editor.put("password", "the password");
editor.commit();
```

If I understand correctly, the actual file that shared prefs writes to is not accessible from other third party apps, correct? Therefore it's ok to store the username + password here?

If I hook up devices to DDMS, I cannot see the shared prefs files (good). If I use the emulator, I can see them.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They shouldn't normally be accessible by other applications, but on a rooted device they can be accessed quite easily.

You may want to [encrypt/decrypt](http://www.androidsnippets.com/encryptdecrypt-strings) the strings as your store and load them.

Comment: Thanks - I can't seem to find anything in the docs that say it is only accessible by your application (on a non-rooted phone). Have you seen anything like that?

Comment: @user to obtain a SharedPreferences instance (either the default or any custom one) you need the Activity context, which is inaccessible by any other app.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. Nevertheless, the file is a regular xml file that could be accessible by any file explorer in a rooted phone, so you should encrypt your data anyway. Never assume that the app will not be used in a rooted phone. Even if the user won't do it, the phone can always be lost/stolen and rooted to extract information.

To answer the question in your comment:

To obtain a SharedPreferences instance (either the default or any custom one) you need the Activity context, which is inaccessible by any other app.

Comment: +1 i don't think it was faster typing, you just typed more ;)